# Give an example of a non-abelian group G with proper subgroups A and B (with $|A|>1$ and $|B|>1$) and AB is also a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

1. Give an example of a non-abelian group G with proper subgroups A and B (with $|A|>1$ and $|B|>1$) and AB is also a subgroup.

I was thinking of using $G=D_4$ as the non-abelian group with the proper subgroups being A is the group of rotations and B is the group of flips. Is this true?

2. Give a different example of a group G (need $|G| \neq 6$) and subgroups A and B where AB is not a subgroup of G.

For this one I haven't been able to think of one.

Comment: For $1.$ the flips do not form a group. Just take the subgroup generated by a single flip, it has order $2$. Works for any $D_n$.

Comment: What do you mean the subgroup generated by a single flip?

Comment: The subgroup $\{1, s\}$ where $s$ is the flip.

Comment: Take $A$ a normal subgroup and $B$ a any subgroup of your group. Then the result follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For $1.$ the flips do not form a group. Just take for $B=\{1,s\}$ the subgroup generated by a single flip $s$, it has order $2$. Works for any $D_n$.

For $2.$, mostly any time you choose $A$, $B$ that are not normal. For example in a $D_n$  take the subgroups generated by two different flips with non-perpendicular axes ( not Klein).

Another example: $A= \{ 1, (1,2)\}$, $B = \{ 1, (1,3)\}$ in some $S_n$. Choose $n>3$ if you need the $|G|>6$ condition.

Indeed $A\cdot B = \{ 1, (1,3), (1,2), (1,3,2)\}$, not closed under inverses, since $(1,3,2)^{-1} = (1,2,3) \not \in A\cdot B$.

Comment: How about the AB being or not being a subgroup?

Comment: @Username Unknown: Added more detail.

Comment: what does it mean $(1,2)$ in $A=\{1,(1,2)\}$?

Comment: @RataMágica: it's the transposition that flips  $1$, $2$. It is an element of the group of permutations of $1$, $\ldots$, $n$, denoted by $S_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a group $G$; and subgroups $H,K$ with $K$ normal. Then $HK$ is a subgroup. Indeed, since $HK=\bigcup hK=\bigcup Kh=KH$, we have $(KH)(KH)=KH$, and $(HK)^{-1}=K^{-1}H^{-1}=KH=HK$. It suffices you find such a group. There are many!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do part 1 is to take one of the subgroups, say $A$, normal in $G$, because it is then known that $AB$ is a subgroup in this case.

But there are examples in which neither $A$ nor $B$ is normal, still $AB$ is a subgroup. Take for instance an odd prime $p$, and the group $G$ of matrices
$$
G = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
:
x, y, x \in F
 \right\},
$$
where $F$ is the field with $p$ elements. Then you can verify that the two subgroups
$$
A = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
:
x \in F
 \right\}
$$
and
$$
B = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & y & y\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
:
y \in F
 \right\}
$$
are not normal in $G$. Still their product is a subgroup
$$
A B = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & u & v\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
:
u, v \in F
 \right\}.
$$